# importing a py script from a main py script

Tags: python, import, package

This is my hierarchy:

```
mainfolder (seen by sys.path)
main.py
subpath
    package.py
    _init_.py
```

So I am trying to "import" `package.py` from `main.py`.

I have a import syntax like this:

```
from mainfolder.subpath import package
```

...but it is not working. Notice `_init_.py` is 0 bytes (nothing in it), does it make package.py still "package"?

Again I want to import the whole script (`package.py`) and then use the functions as object.function. Suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want `from subpath import package`